# Proper way of migrating from Shotwell to Photos?

Tags: photos

i have switched from Ubuntu to ElementaryOS, which means Shotwell has been replaced by Photos (ie: pantheon-photos).

I don't want to install Shotwell on ElementaryOS, as that would go agains the idea of simplifying and using ElementaryOS's native apps, and, simply, Photos is the continuation of Shotwell.

In order to migrate my Shotwell-managed photos to Photos, what do I need to do?
Are there any other steps beyond copying the Shotwell database located at `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db` in my old Ubuntu home directory to `~/.local/share/io.elementary.photos/data/photo.db` in my new ElementaryOS home directory and then starting up Photos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In light of the lack of answer, i eventually went ahead and tried the solution described in my question.
It appears to work fine: copying the Shotwell database located at `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db` in the old home directory to `~/.local/share/io.elementary.photos/data/photo.db` in the new ElementaryOS home directory and then starting up Elementary Photos results in Elementary Photos finding the pictures, events, tags, etc..

You just want to make sure you start Elementary Photos a first time before doing the database copy step described above and change the settings to adjust where Elementary Photos should import pictures and whether it should automatically import pictures, in case you want to avoid adding pictures to your library that shouldn't be there. By default, Elementary Photos will scan and add everything located in your user's Pictures directory (`~/Pictures`).